# NPOCO PL/SQL HANDELING OUT PARAMETERS

Tags: oracle, plsql, npoco

I have stored procedure in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procTest (p_param1 varchar2, p_param2 out varchar2)
AS
BEGIN
... 
END;
```

How can I handle out parameters?

```
_db.Execute("EXEC procTest ('dsds')");
```

Answer (score -2):

reed about Stored Procedures And Functions Support on http://pocoproject.org/docs-1.5.0/00200-DataUserManual.html

> **Stored Procedures And Functions Support**
>
> Most of the modern database systems support stored procedures and/or functions. Does Poco::Data provide any support there? You bet. While the specifics on what exactly is possible (e.g. the data types passed in and out, automatic or manual data binding, binding direction, etc.) is ultimately database dependent, POCO Data does it's best to provide reasonable access to such functionality through in, out and io binding functions. As their names imply, these functions are performing parameters binding tho pass in or receive from the stored procedures, or both. The code is worth thousand words, so here's an Oracle ODBC example:

```
session << "CREATE OR REPLACE "
    "FUNCTION storedFunction(param1 IN OUT NUMBER, param2 IN OUT NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS "
    " temp NUMBER := param1; "
    " BEGIN param1 := param2; param2 := temp; RETURN(param1+param2); "
    " END storedFunction;" , now;

int i = 1, j = 2, result = 0;
session << "{? = call storedFunction(?, ?)}", out(result), io(i), io(j), now; // i = 2, j = 1, result = 3
```

> Stored procedures are allowed to return data sets (a.k.a. cursors):

```
typedef Tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string, int> Person;
std::vector<Person> people;
int age = 13;
session << "CREATE OR REPLACE "
    "FUNCTION storedCursorFunction(ageLimit IN NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS "
    " ret SYS_REFCURSOR; "
    "BEGIN "
    " OPEN ret FOR "
    " SELECT *  FROM Person  WHERE Age < ageLimit; " 
    " RETURN ret; "
    "END storedCursorFunction;" , now;

session << "{call storedCursorFunction(?)}", in(age), into(people), now;
```

> The code shown above works with Oracle databases.